# go expression seems to not follow order of operations

Tags: go

In `go` I am getting two different answers to equations that should be evaluating the same as far as I can see... I am doing the `go` tour and I am on this page ( https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/8 )

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Sqrt(x float64) float64 {
    z := 1.0
    for i := 0; i < int(x); i++ {
        z = z - ((z * z - x) / 2 * z)
        fmt.Println(z)
    }
    return z
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(9))
}
```

Here is the code that I initially wrote that was not working, It seems that I "NEED" parentheses like this...

```
z = z - ((z * z - x) / (2 * z))
```

But I cannot see any reason why I would need to specify the order of operations like that since it seems like it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `a / b * c` is grouped as `(a / b) * c`.  The expression `a / (b * c)` is grouped as shown. The first multiplies by `c`. The second divides by `c`.